# How can I install the latest Google Chrome on Mac OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, google-chrome

Google Chrome updated itself as 67.0:

[image]

and then, when I restart, Google Chrome reports itself as "outdated" and brought me to a download page, and let me download a `.dmg` image.  After I mount it and drag the image to the App folder, it then said it is version 65.0.

How do I install the latest version of Google Chrome on OS X Mavericks?  (I kept Mavericks because I like the iBooks highlighting of simulating a real highlighter, but actually, I found that in Mavericks, that feature was gone, and yet I still may update later, as in the past, upgrading the OS have caused my machine not able to boot up and one time I spent close to 8 hours trying to fix it and eventually had to restore it from the backup).

Answer (score 1):

Try going to https://www.google.com/chrome/ in Safari on Mavericks and it should offer you to download the latest available update for Mavericks.

However, Chrome will still report itself as outdated, because they have dropped support for Mavericks, and running Chrome risks security issues, etc.